# PHP not loading postgresql extensions ( mac os x)

Tags: php, macos, apache, postgresql

my currently extension folder in php is ( executing php-config --extension-dir)

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
```

Inside this directory i have my postgresql extensions that i need to load

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   32940 Feb 25 17:12 pdo_pgsql.so
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  135652 Feb 25 23:55 pgsql.so
```

On the php.ini that is shown by phpinfo() i have this lines uncommented

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

Php and postgre were installed with brew.
And i "make" both pgsql.so and pdo_pgsql.so with the php source files corresponding to my actual version which is 5.6.5

Every time i call pg_connect it shows me a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

The version i had  wasn´t built with the `--with-postgresql` option in brew so i uninstalled the php56 and then reinstalled it with the option mentioned before following all the instructions

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

You can get the post installation insctructions with `brew info php56` in my case.

With the php built with postgresql you don´t need to add the pgsql.so and pdo_pgsql.so extensions in the php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally: the PDO extension can be installed with `$ brew install php56-pdo-pgsql`.

Comment: In fact, you can just `brew reinstall php56 --with-postgresql` to add support with uninstalling

Answer (score 0):

Updating the php version worked for me:

> curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6